# Multithreaded server - design approach

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, mutex

I have a systemd service which acts as a server for incoming requests (API endpoint). Additionally, this service should monitor the state of the system (cpu load, ram, etc.), this is done by reading in the appropriate files in the /proc filesystem. I plan to update these values each second by spawning a dedicated thread, which will continuously read in the new values.

To my understanding a thread pool would be the wrong pattern to apply here, since these threads (probably around 4 in total) are long running (start and termination depends on the lifetime of the service). What would be a proper approach to manage these threads?

In my current implementation I have a dedicated class for each thread with some helper functions:

```
class Example{
  public:
    Example() {
      t = std::thread{&Example::run, this};
    }

    ~Example() {
      t.join();
    }

    void read();  // read from /proc fs
    void set();   // update values
    void get();  // access to private data member
    void run();  // thread loop, will call read and set each second
    
    std::thread t;

  private:
    int data;  // type int to keep it simple
}
```

The server then manually starts each thread on startup:

```
// constructor snippet
// these are member variables
t1 = Example1();
t2 = Example2();
t3 = Example3();
t4 = Example4();
```

I'm not sure if this is a proper approach to handle multiple, long running threads. Would it be better to create a dedicated class which handles all threads, so that the server would just have to manage this one object? Are there any other patterns for this kind of work?

Also the thread should be the only one updating the corresponding value, but there could be multiple reads happen at the same time, should a mutex be used during the update process?

Comment: This really depends on the type of work you're doing, and if you need a work queue, or can just have at it with specialized threads. I usually find it's better to have a generic thread pool of "workers" and then you queue up tasks that are processed by the first available thread.

Comment: Not an answer. Consider using [Poco::Net::HTTPServer](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html), which manages threads itself along with thread-safety value access

Comment: @tadman the work is simple, read a file, do some calculations, update values accordingly. This work must be repeated each second for multiple different values. Hence my initial use of 4 threads, each dedicated to some specific work (e.g. one to read in and calculate cpu usage, one to read in and do some work with temperature, etc.). Also these reads should not be blocked by one another.

Comment: Reading files in the `/proc` filesystem is dirt-cheap since they aren't real files. I don't see any reason to use dedicated threads for this. If your API endpoint has a timeout parameter, I suggest you just use that for your periodic updates.

Comment: you wont benefit that much from using a thread pool when the threads a long running in terms of spwaning the threads, but that doesnt mean that you should not use one.

Comment: If you want 4 threads then you eventually have to manage 4 thread objects *somehow*. Whether you put them in an AllMyThreads class or just have 4 loose thread objects is up to you. Which one seems easier?